# Python3 dice game, how to rank players based on their scores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

I'm creating a dice game here. So far, I've created the game to ask for how many players and I keep every player's score in a dictionary.

Now, I want to use that scores and compare between players so at the end of the game every player will know their ranks.

I want something like this will print out "5th: Mike", "6th: Steve: ". I really don't know how to do that. Hope you guys can help me, here's the code.

```
from random import randint


def main():
    player = int(input('How many players> '))
    step = 1
    player += 1
    player_dict = {}
    scores_dict = {}

    for pl in range(1, player, step):
        player_name = input(f'Player {str(pl)} name> ') # Get players name from user input
        player_dict[pl] = player_name

    for x in player_dict:
        score = roll_dice(player_dict[x])
        scores_dict[player_dict[x]] = score


def roll_dice(player_name):
    start_rolling = input(f'{player_name} roll dice? y/n> ')
    if start_rolling == 'y' or start_rolling == 'Y':
        roll = randint(1, 6)
        print(f'{player_name} rolls a {roll}')
        return roll
    return

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is probably to eliminate `scores_dict` by incorporating it into `player_dict`, and have the player dict's values be a two-member list, as follows:

```
    player_dict = {} 

    for pl in range(1, player, step):
        player_name = input(f'Player {str(pl)} name> ') 
        player_dict[pl] = [player_name, 0]  #each dict value is a list, initial score = 0

    for x in player_dict:
        score = roll_dice(player_dict[x][0]) #the player name is at list index 0
        player_dict[x][1] = score #the player score is at list index 1
    
    results = [x for x in player_dict.items()] #make a sortable list from the dict
    #sort the list in reverse order, using a key function that looks at scores:
    sorted_results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True) 

    print([x[1] for x in sorted_results]) #view a ranked list of players & scores
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops into mind is that there can be duplicate scores, which needs to be handled.  You can get all the values of a dictionary via the `.values()` method.  You can use `set()` to remove duplicates. You can use `sorted(the_list, reverse=True)` to get the biggest score first.  (In Py3.8, `sorted()` will accept a set as input.)  Then iterate through the sorted list, which will give you each value one at a time, and with that value iterate through the list of players to see who got that score, printing out their names. You probably want something like:

```
1st: Adam
2nd: Bob and Barry are tied
   :
   :
5th: Mike
6th: Steve
```

Maybe something like:

```
for index, score in enumerate(sorted(set(scores_dict.values()), reverse=True):
    player_list = [p for p in player_dict.values() if score_dict[p] == score]
    if len(player_list) == 1:
        print("{rank}: {player}".format(rank=index+1, player=player_list[0]))
    else:
        print("{rank}: {players} are tied".format(rank=index+1, players=' and '.join(player_list)))
```

`enumerate()` is a great routine that adds numbering to the return values.

`[p for p in player_dict.values() if score_dict[p] == score]` is a list comprehension, which creates a list from the input statements.
[x*x for x in [0, 1, 2]] would return [0, 1, 4]

[x*x for x in [0, 1, 2] if x < 2] adds a condition and would return [0, 1]

Also, as a side note, it is not clear that you need two dicts for this data.  You could probably just have player_dict, and have the player name as the key and the score as the value, unless you for some reason do need to preserve the player number id.